# Align word of two lines

Tags: spacing, lists, alignment

In order to highlight a parallelism between two lines, I want to align specific words.

The following example is from a list in Peano's Formulario preface:

[image: example]

> c) suppressione de ι κ λ … ρ σ …
>   que resulta expresso per 10 20 30 … 100 200 …

I used `\usepackage{enumitem}\setenumerate[1]{label={\alph*)}}` to reproduce the list style.

My first thought was to use a table but it seems not to be compatible with the list alignement.

Comment: You can use tables in a list environment, but use only the `\begin{tabular}` part, not the `\begin{table}` (the latter is just so that the table floats between pages, which you do not want here).

Comment: What exactly do you want to align? The Greek letters and the numbers in the line below?

Comment: Yes like in the screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the third item in a `[t]`op-aligned `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setenumerate[1]{label={\alph*)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item

  \item Second item

  \item 
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l *{7}{c} @{}}
    suppressione de          & $\iota$ & $\chi$ & $\lambda$ & \ldots & $\rho$ & $\sigma$ & \ldots \\
    que resulta expresso per &    10   &   20   &     30    & \ldots &   100  &    200   & \ldots
  \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Much better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a normal `table/tabular` or maybe a `tabbing` environment (see below and [here](http://www.ctex.org/documents/latex/latex2e-html/ltx-58.html) (external link)).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabbing}
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx \= xxx \= xxx \= xxx \= xxx \kill % Not printed. Just for reserving space.
    c) TextText \> $i$ \> $\chi$ \> \ldots \> $\sigma$\\
    AnotherTextText \> $10$ \> $20$ \> \ldots \> $100$\\
  \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*PS: This is surely not an elegant solution. It just came into my mind.*

Comment: What are the x's for? How to determine how many to put in?

Comment: @Blincer The `x` reserves space. I just played with the number of `x`. You do not need to use `x`, you can use normal letters.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabto}\NumTabs{11}
\def\|{\tab}
\begin{document}
suppressione de\|\| $\iota$\|$\chi$\|$\lambda$\|\ldots\|$\rho$\|$\sigma$\|\ldots\\
que resulta expresso per\|10\|20\|30\|\ldots\|100\|200\|\ldots
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `\NumTabs{11}` for?

Comment: @Blincer Try to change to ``\NumTabs{2}``, for instance ... It is not evident?